# Placing div's in specific order using css flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I'm new to using css flex. What i want to accomplish is the following. I have a parent div with 4 children. On desktop every child needs be 50% width of the parent, so in that case 2 div's per row.
On mobile phone/tablet, i want to every child to fill 100% width of the screen, so 1 child per row.

This is what i already tried

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.full {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.left,
.right,
.left2,
.right2 {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}

.left {
  background-color: red;
}

.right {
  background-color: blue;
}

.left2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.right2 {
  background-color: green;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .full {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="full">
  <div class="left">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
    eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  </div>
  <div class="left2">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  </div>
  <div class="right2">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: keep the direction row and change flex: 1 1 50%; to flex: 1 1 100%;

Comment: The desktop version is still the same after doing that, and on phone i need to scroll to the right to see all the other divs, on phone i want them to be placed underneath eachother not next to eachother

Comment: Here's also a very simple paint example of the order from the divs per device https://prnt.sc/qz5i8d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I understood your purpose, is to display the div in a specific manner. I advise you to use `display: grid` rather than **flex**.

For more details : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout

Here is your code with flex. Just two line's of code could get the task done.

*If its mandatory to use flex, please do let me know in the comments.*

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
```

```css
  html,
    body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .full {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    }

    .left,
    .right,
    .left2,
    .right2 {
        flex: 1 1 50%;
    }

    .left {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .right {
        background-color: blue;
    }

    .left2 {
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    .right2 {
        background-color: green;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
        .full {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        }
    }
```

```html
  <div class="full">
        <div class="left">
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
            ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
            nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
            anim id est laborum."
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
            ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
            nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
            anim id est laborum."
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
            ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
            nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
            anim id est laborum."
        </div>
        <div class="left2">
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
            ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
            nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
            anim id est laborum."
        </div>
        <div class="right2">
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
            ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
            nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
            anim id est laborum."
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Only thing that needs to be changed is on the desktop variant `grid-template-columns: 2 1fr` so that there are 2 divs per row on desktop. Why is grid better than using flex?

Comment: Both of them has got their own purposes. Here your intention is to layout the things so the apt one is grid.

Comment: You could do it also as : grid-template-columns:repeat(<number of columns>,1fr) .. For you edit it as grid-template-columns:repeat(2,1fr)l

Comment: Thank you! I first tried it with normal css like inline-block, but that leaves a little gap between the 2 divs per row, only solutions were ugly fixes like float or font-size: 0; etc

Comment: I recommed reading this to get 100% out of it : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout

Answer (score 0):

Just a few minor tweaks to your code.  Flexbox is fine for this kind of thing

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100vu;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.full {
  width: 100%;
  
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-direction: row;
 }

.left,
.right,
.left2,
.right2 {
width:50%;
   
}

.left {
  background-color: red;
}

.right {
  background-color: blue;
}

.left2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.right2 {
  background-color: green;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .full {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items:center;    
  }
  .left,
.right,
.left2,
.right2 {
width:100%;
   
}
}
```

```html
<div class="full">
  <div class="left">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
    eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  </div>
  <div class="left2">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  </div>
  <div class="right2">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, for now i used grid, but i'll try to learn more flex in the upcoming days!